# Backup GPG private key in KeePassXC

Tags: privacy, key-management, gnupg, pgp, openpgp

In order to keep all my secret in the same place, I would like to store my GPG private key in KeePassXC, under the "Notes" field.

Provided that the db file has very good password, is this safe?

Os this field encrypted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire database is encrypted including the notes. The security of both the program and the file format is analysed indepth in [KeePassXC Application Security Review](https://keepassxc.org/assets/pdf/KeePassXC-Review-V1-Molotnikov.pdf) by Zaur Molotnikov. From the summary:

> KeePassXC provides sufficient cryptographic protection
> (confidentiality, integrity and authenticity) to the confidential
> information the user is storing in the database, given that the user
> selects a strong authentication method, e.g. a strong passphrase and a
> confidential random key file, and that the user will use KeePassXC
> with its latest secure file format.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can attach your private key file under Advanced/Attachments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).